# Keep empty GRID Cells in PostgreSQL (after join)

Tags: postgresql

I want to join a 100*100m Grid  with a point layer. The points contain the number of people living in the grid cell. There are some cells with no polulation, which I want to keep with the Attribute "pop_count = 0". My SQL-Query unfortunately gives back only the cells in which the attribut >0 exists (see picture).

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.routing_join;
    CREATE TABLE public.routing_join as
    SELECT pop_count, grid.wkb_geometry
      FROM population, grid
      WHERE ST_Intersects(population.wkb_geometry, grid.wkb_geometry);
```

How can I change my query to keep the empty cells?

[image: Fill empty cells]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using a join to intersect the features, rather than in a where clause, which gives you the option to use RIGHT JOIN:

```
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.routing_join;
        CREATE TABLE public.routing_join as
        SELECT pop_count, grid.wkb_geometry
          FROM population
   right join grid on ST_Intersects(population.wkb_geometry, grid.wkb_geometry);
```

However: running this I get the correct geometry back, but I get an error:

```
NOTICE:  gserialized_gist_joinsel: jointype 1 not supported
```

There are some posts about this, so I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For me this solutions worked without error.

Comment: @Peter ok good - gotta figure out what this error means... Thanks!!!